# Get All Row Values After Split and Put Them In List

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, dataframe

UPDATED: I've the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sports': ["['soccer', 'men tennis']", "['soccer']", "['baseball', 'women tennis']"]})

print(df)
                         sports
0      ['soccer', 'men tennis']
1                    ['soccer']
2  ['baseball', 'women tennis']
```

I need to extract all the unique sport names and put them into a list. I'm trying the following code:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(df['sports'].str.split(',').tolist()).stack()
out.value_counts().index
```

However, it's returning `Nan` values.

**Desired output:**

```
['soccer', 'men tennis', 'baseball', 'women tennis']
```

What would be the smartest way of doing it? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are lists, then you could `explode` + `unique`:

```
out = df['sports'].explode().unique().tolist()
```

If these are strings, then you could use `ast.literal_eval` first to parse it:

```
import ast
out = df['sports'].apply(ast.literal_eval).explode().unique().tolist()
```

or use `ast.literal_eval` in a set comprehension and unpack:

```
out = [*{x for lst in df['sports'].tolist() for x in ast.literal_eval(lst)}]
```

Output:

```
['soccer', 'men tennis', 'baseball', 'women tennis']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the type of values stored in `sports` column is `list`, we can flatten the column using `hstack`, then use `set` to get unique values

```
set(np.hstack(df['sports']))
```

---

```
{'baseball', 'men tennis', 'soccer', 'women tennis'}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
lst = []
df['sports'].apply(lambda x: [lst.append(element) for element in x])
lst = list(set(lst))
```

Not sure how efficient is this, but works.